# How to use Droplist types in Sitecore template fields

Tags: sitecore

Is there anyone who knows how to use "Droplist" type in template fields?

I guess "Droplist" is the same as `<select><option></option></select>` type.

I'd like to specify select list types with static values so that Sitecore editors can select only one of many available lists when they create a page.
My plan is to add CSS class names (`<option>`) in the list (`<select>`) and editors will use one of styles by selecting one of them.

How to add the values in select list?  Do I have to write code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Droplist` is similar to the `Droplink` field type in that they are both dropdowns. The `Droplist` will only store the name of the item (so it will not have a link to that item), while the `Droplink` stores the ID of the item. That means if you rename an option, or move it elsewhere in your Content Tree, the `Droplist` will not update (resulting in possible broken links), the Droplink will update.

You can add values to the `Droplist` by setting the `Datasource` field in the templates to something (for instance `/sitecore/content/Home/CSS/` if that's where you would like to store your CSS class names).

You can access the `Droplist` in code like so:

```cs
Item item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
string css = item["FieldName"]; // Also possible is item.Fields["Fieldname"].Value;
```

A `Droplink` could be accessed like this:

```cs
string dropDownItemId = item["Fieldname"]; // Or, again, item.Fields["Fieldname"].Value; if you prefer
var cssItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dropDownItemId); // And now you can
// access any fields in this item.
```

**Edit**
[A good article going into some more detail in the differences between Droplink and Droplist](https://backtocoding.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/sitecore-droplist-vs-droplink/)

Comment: If I need to create datasource in /sitecore/content/Home/CSS/, that means I have to create CSS folder and add items in the folder? So, what template type do I have to use? If I create an item which named "css-class-name ss-name" something like this as class name values, the item name in CSS folder should be the data value??

Comment: Yes, if that's where you want to have your CSS definitions. You can use whatever template you want, it all depends on your requirements (do you want to use the name only or do you want to be able to add CSS to the item as well? If you go with droplist then yes, "css-class-name ss-name" should be the name of the item. You can also use a Droplink and have a value field in which you can add the name

Comment: If I check the __standard value in template, I could see droplink lists from datasource. So, I create a page used the template, but I can't select the list shown in __standard value in the page item's content area, just empty field.

Comment: Good info from Trayek here.  One minor correction: You CAN rename a Droplist target item, and Sitecore will update the referring field values.  Sitecore does track links for Droplists.  This is why they will show up in the broken links report if they have an invalid value.  Moving the target item, of course, breaks the link, since the text value in the field must be an item name under the given DataSource.

Answer (score 3):

I would proceed exactly as @Trayek suggested in his solution. To expand on that, this should be your implementation:

You create your own template, maybe called *CSS Class*, and you will add a Single-Line Text field to it, maybe called *Value*. You will put the actual CSS classes in that field when you create the items.

Next, you will add a folder item somewhere in the Content tree, and you will add your *CSS Class* items to that folder. That folder will also be the datasource of your droplist/droplink.

To set your datasource, [this blog post](http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2014/june/26/constraining-the-sitecore-7-multilist-and-treelist-fields-with-and-without-search) should be of help. You will be looking to use *number 1* under *For Fields without Search* (screenshot included, below). I wrote the article a while back, so if you need any additional help just let me know.

[image]

Comment: Heads up, the link to that blog post is down so there's no example of how to set a DataSource for a droplist/droplink.

Comment: @alex Thanks for letting me know - I forgot to renew my Sitecore license. I have a temporary one that I can put up while I wait for the new one. Must have gone down this morning. It will be back up in the next few minutes

Comment: @alex - The site is back up. I would appreciate you removing your downvote when you get a chance. Thanks, again.

Comment: I have also added a screenshot in case there are any further disruptions on my blog.

Comment: Thanks Zach, the blog link's still down, but +1 for the screenshot.