# Sitecore The field contains a value that is not in the selection list

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I have an item "`newsItem`" in sitecore with a field "`Recipient`"
Here is a screen shot of item's Template with **Name**, **Type** and **Source**.

[image: sitecore droplist field]

I want to assign an Id to the item from code behind

```cs
newsItem["Recipient"] = GetRecipientFromRadioButton();

private string GetRecipientFromRadioButton()
{
    //Get the item 
    Item enumerationNewsRecipientsItemId = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Site Config/Enumerations/News Recipients");

    foreach (Item item in enumerationNewsRecipientsItemId.Children)
    {
        if //Some Condition
            return item.ID.ToString();
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Now for this item I am seeing following in content editor '**The field contains a value that is not in the selection list**.'. Although the ID is one of the ID from items under `/sitecore/content/Site Config/Enumerations/News Recipients`

[image: field contains a value that is not in the selection list]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Droplist` stores only name of the item. That why when you try to set it to `ID` it  says that this value is not present in the selection list.

You should use **`Droplink`** type instead.

I've copied part of the answer from [Sitecore Droplist Type in Template Field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28055759/157833) so question:

> The `Droplist` is similar to the `Droplink` field type in that they are both dropdowns. The `Droplist` will only store the name of the item (so it will not have a link to that item), while the `Droplink` stores the ID of the item. That means if you rename an option, or move it elsewhere in your Content Tree, the `Droplist` will not update (resulting in possible broken links), the `Droplink` will update.

See more detailed explanation here [Sitecore: Droplist vs. Droplink](https://backtocoding.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/sitecore-droplist-vs-droplink/).